# Is $ \lbrace e^{\large\frac{s}{\log x}} : s \in \Bbb R \rbrace $ a useless group?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

Given the group: $ G_1 = \lbrace e^{\large\frac{s}{\log x}} : s \in \Bbb R \rbrace $,
with multiplication as the operation and $1$ as the identity element,

Is this group of any interest? It makes a correspondence between elements of the form: $ e^{\large\frac{s}{\log x}} $ and real numbers $s$, but couldn't you just use the real numbers as a group just as easily? Isn't it just an overly complicated group?

Edit:

How does $ G_2 $ compare to $ G_1 $, where  $G_2 = \lbrace \zeta(s)^{\large\frac{1}{\log x}} : s \in \Bbb R \rbrace $, where $\zeta(s) $ is the Riemann zeta function. There is only one inverse for all $s$ correct?

Comment: Where is $x$ defined?

Comment: It is an overly-complicated definition of $(\mathbb R^{+},\times)$ which is isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+).$

Comment: everywhere except at x=0 and x=1

Comment: Well, it's not a group in those cases, either. @geocalc33

Comment: Define "useless".

Comment: Your question has two answers already, so you should *not* edit your question in such a way as to make these answers meaningless (as you have done). Instead, you should ask your more complicated question as a new question (and link back to this one if you think it is helpful).

Comment: (I rolled back these edits for the above reason.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, inherently the group $G_1$ you are describing is just the positive real numbers under multiplication. You just have a rather complicated way of describing it.

However, I think it's worth pointing out that, beyond the literal meaning of the symbols, there is something of substance here: Implicitly, you are thinking of a map $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ given by
$$s\mapsto x^s$$
where $x$ is a positive real number. This is a group homomorphism (and, in fact, an isomorphism for $x\neq 1$). This map is an isomorphism, which means that, as far as group structure goes, the positive real numbers under multiplication act the same as real numbers under addition. So, from some points of view, yes, this is just an odd way of referring to the usual group $\mathbb R$.

A common theme in mathematics is that isomorphic objects can carry different implications - note that there are *many* isomorphisms between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^+$, so they can't be *canonically* identified. For instance, if you were doing geometry and wanted to consider, say, the set of dilations from a point as a group, you would naturally end up working in $\mathbb R^+$ rather than $\mathbb R$. So, I wouldn't say that it is useless, even if it's isomorphic to a more common group.

Comment: Even if there's more than one isomorphism between groups (or other objects) that doesn't mean there's no preferred isomorphism between them. In our case, $\exp : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^+$ is certainly a distinguished group isomorphism $(\Bbb R, +) \stackrel{\cong}{\to} (\Bbb R^+, \cdot)$.

Comment: what if $s$ was a complex number would you then be describing the complex numbers under multiplication instead of the real numbers under multiplication

Comment: If $s$ is complex and $x$ is real, then $x^s=e^{s\log x}$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: For example, $x^{2\pi i/\log x} = 1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what happens from a group theory perspective when you integrate over the kernel $x^s$ i.e. $\int_0^1 x^{s}~dx$?

Answer (score 4):

*This should really be a comment, but it's too long.*

The group (for $x$ positive and $\not=1$) is just $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)$, described in an unnecessarily messy way. However, there is a neat *map* involved here.

For every positive $x$ other than $1$, the map $$\varphi_x: s\mapsto e^{s\over\log x}$$ is a group isomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)$. So in a certain sense, what your notation is really doing is describing a **continuously$^1$ varying group**: to each positive $x$ other than $1$, you've assigned a copy $C_x$ of $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},\times)$, and they're intuitively "stretching" as we vary $x$. For example, $\varphi_e(1)=e$ and $\varphi_{e^2}(1)=\sqrt{e}$, so in some sense the $e$ of $C_e$ corresopnds to the $\sqrt{e}$ of $C_{e^2}$. Indeed, we can picture a "thread" running through the groups $C_x$ corresponding to the number $1$ in $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

This sort of "continuously varying object" is actually quite important in mathematics. Elsewhere you'll see the same basic idea (broadly speaking) occurring in many contexts. As an example, you might think about how to view a Mobius strip as a "continuously (over a circle) varying line" - that is, [a line bundle over a circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_bundle).

---

$^1$You may not be familiar at this point with the subject of [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology), but the point is that all the pieces involved in this picture have a sort of "geometry" associated to them, and all the transformations we're describing here are "continuous" in the sense of that geometry. It's not important at this stage to dive into that if you're not already familiar with the basics; for now, just see if you can get an intuitive sense that when we change $x$ very slightly, the copy $C_x$ only distorts "a little" (somewhat more concretely, if $x$ is very close to $y$ then $e^{s\over \log x}$ is very close to $e^{s\over\log y}$).

Comment: what if you changed the map from $ e^s $ to some other measure?

Comment: @geocalc33 What do you mean "some other measure?"

Comment: @geocalc33 Well, exponentiation is good here because it yields a group homomorphism, since $e^se^t=e^{s+t}$. But $(\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^s})\cdot(\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^t})$ is not in general equal to $\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k^{s+t}}$.

Comment: I mean that whole summation raised to the 1/log(x) power. So would that not work because it's not generally equal?

Comment: @geocalc33 Well, I don't know what "work" means in this context. It wouldn't correspond to a "continuously varying group" in the strict sense of my answer, but it would in a looser sense. It all depends what you're trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79009/discussion-between-geocalc33-and-noah-schweber).